# JQuery And JavaScript Search AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, input, autocomplete

I have an HTML code with this line:

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

And a JS file with those:

```
var arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
$('#search').autocomplete({ source: arr });
```

I am trying to make a autocomplete for a search engine, But i cant display my results in my HTML Web page.

I was looking at some answers and seen people that says it work.
Any idea why it doesnt work for me?

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle that reproduces the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete function you are using is from jqueryUI.Have you included it?

Comment: i included JQuery with those lines in my HTML:                                                         
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: You need to include jqueryUI along with jquery. <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You need to include JQuery UI, not just JQuery:

```
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You! needed the UI